# Can't display base64 image retrieved from mongodb in React ERR_INVALID_URL

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to display an image retrieved from mongodb, but I keep getting ERR_INVALID_URL: http://prntscr.com/tzyqtd

In mongodb it is defined as:

```
coverImage: {
  type: Buffer,
},
```

In node I am reading the image with fs:

```
const img = fs.readFileSync(
  path.resolve(__dirname, "../../images/img/grippers/gripper1.png"),
  { encoding: "base64" }
);
```

Then I save it in mongodb by simply giving that `img` to the `coverImage` field.

On my front end side when I make the request I do get the object with the image in it:

```
const retrievedConfig = await axios.get(
  `http://localhost:3000/config/one/ROBOT_1`
);

console.log(retrievedConfig.data.Configs[0].Pallet.coverImage);
```

So this does output the image and the image contains two fields, `{type: Buffer, data: Array[3750]}`

Then when I try to render it:

```
<img src={`data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,${img.data.toString("base64")}`}/>
```

It gives me the `ERR_INVALID_URL` error.

Now, one thing I have noticed is that even with the `toString("base64")` I dont think it actually converts into base64 for some reason, because its still in 8 bit numbers (0 to 255). http://prntscr.com/tzysh5

But when I read it with fs on the backend it is in base64 http://prntscr.com/tzysrz (that is right after the fs.read and before the saving in the db)

`EDIT:` I tried using the `btoa` function on the front end and it did convert it into base64 (however I have no clue why the other way didnt work, I have the exact same code in another application working without btoa and images being displayed), but even after the conversion it was still not displaying the image (just showing a broken image http://prntscr.com/tzyw1m ), but no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue recently - what worked for me is was to manually convert the data from a `Uint8Array` to base64:

```
function convertBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    let binaryStr = '';
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
      binaryStr += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return btoa(binary);
  }
```

Use it like this:

```
<img src={`data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,${convertBufferToBase64(img.data)}`}/>
```

EDIT:

Since you're already reading the image using the `{ encoding: "base64" }` option, there should be no need to convert between buffers. Changing the mongoose-datatype of `coverImage` to `String` and using its value in the frontend should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt help either it still shows it as a broken image

Comment: Just to be sure - can you verify that the base64 string is a valid image? You  can try it here for example:https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: okay, I have tried with the image after it is generated on the server side, that one renders just fine, but the other when it is converted back on the react side is not a valid image and the string is different

Comment: Wait a sec - you're reading the file using `{ encoding: "base64" }` meaning that `img` will actually already be a base64-encoded string. There should be no need to convert from/to buffers. Can you try to change the coverImage type to `String`?

Comment: that worked! I changed to string and removed all conversions on the front end side and it worked. Thanks. Edit your answer so that I can accept it.